# Google Maps API - Get URL to address

Tags: api, google-maps

Is there a way in the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) to create an URL to Google Maps self?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the API.
Just use

> http://maps.google.com/?q=1+Infinite+Loop,+95014+(Some+Title+Here)